# Mutation for projectV2Item (Github projects)

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

At first, my primary language is not english, so i hope to be clear in my explanation.

I'm using Github Projects and graphql API. There I have 2 projectsV2, one is a "input" project and the other one is a "output", so i have a query to check the issues in each project (just need to change node_id). I can get the card or item (not sure if it's the same) fields and custom fields, but later it's necessary to take that item and send it to the other projectV2.

So the step by step is:

- I create a item in "output" and fill the necessary info in the default fields and custom-fields (ex: "sendedBy")
- I run a query telling that I'm doing a request from "output" to get the node_id value and later run a query to get all the fields of the card (important)
- Later I need to create the new item in the other project (I already have the node_id with all the other queries I did before) so i think i need to use a mutation.

So the problem is, which mutation method should I use to create the projectV2Item and link the customFields (and values for each one) to this new item.